# How to set text field about product name below of each image in grid view

Tags: android

****How to set text below of each image in Grid view**

> > i want to set text about product name below of each image when i click this  text so it     goes to full image a activity please help me.this is my code

### This is my Android Grid Activity code

```
package com.a.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class AndroidGridActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.gridview);

GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

// Instance of ImageAdapter Class
gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
/**
* On Click event for Single Gridview Item
     * */
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
int position, long id) {

// Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
// passing array index
i.putExtra("id", position);
startActivity(i);
}
});
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
int position, long id) {

// Sending text id to FullScreenActivity
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),  FullImageActivity.class);
// passing array index
i.putExtra("id", position);
startActivity(i);
}
});
}
}`
```

---

This is layout file of android grid view activity

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/chooseText"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="85dp"
android:text="TextView"
android:layout_below="@+id/chooseImage"
android:gravity="center"
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:textColor="#3232FF">
</TextView>
<GridView 
android:id="@+id/grid_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:columnWidth="90dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth" 
android:background="#0000FF">  

</GridView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

This is my full image class
    package com.example.androidhive;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class FullImageActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.full_image);

// get intent data
Intent i = getIntent();
// Selected image id
int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);

// get intent data
Intent in = getIntent();

// Selected text id
int positiont = in.getExtras().getInt("id");
ImageAdapter imageAdaptert = new ImageAdapter(this);

TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fulltext);
txtView.setText(imageAdapter.mThumbTxt[position]);
}

}
```

---

Its a full image layout code

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/full_image_view"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"/>
<TextView
android:id="@+id/fulltext"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:textColor="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

its image adapter class
    package com.example.androidhive;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

// Keep all Images in array
public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
R.drawable.pic_1, R.drawable.pic_2,
R.drawable.pic_3, R.drawable.pic_4,
R.drawable.pic_5, R.drawable.pic_6,
R.drawable.pic_7, R.drawable.pic_8,
R.drawable.pic_9, R.drawable.pic_10,
R.drawable.pic_11, R.drawable.pic_12,
R.drawable.pic_13, R.drawable.pic_14,

};

// Constructor
public ImageAdapter(Context c){
mContext = c;
}


public int getCount() {
return mThumbIds.length;
}


public Object getItem(int position) {
return null;
}


public long getItemId(int position) {
return 0;
}


// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ImageView imageView;

if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
} else {
imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
}

imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
return imageView;
}

public String[] mThumbTxt = {
"Müzeler", "Anıtlar", "İbadethaneler",   "Hepsi","iqra","rafia","sana","sobia","amna","aisha","asma","asna","urosa","asnam"
};
public View getView1(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
View view = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.gridview, null);
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relaGrid);

ImageView image = (ImageView) rl.findViewById(R.id.chooseImage);
TextView text = (TextView) rl.findViewById(R.id.chooseText);       
image.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
text.setText(mThumbTxt[position]);
return rl;
}
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://android-expert.blogspot.com/2012/02/gridview-with-image-and-textview.html) and [this post](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/)

Answer (score 0):

Refer below code

```
        GridView sdcardImages = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.sdcard);
        sdcardImages.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(myImages, myViews));
        sdcardImages.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {
                Intent i = new Intent(EquipmentViews.this, VIRDemo.class);
                i.putExtra("EquipmentId", equipmentIds[position]);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
```

Then create adapter

```
private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private int[] myRemoteImages;
    private String[] myRemoteViews;

    public ImageAdapter(int[] myimages, String[] myviews) {
        myRemoteImages = myimages;
        myRemoteViews = myviews;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.myRemoteImages.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.imageitem, null);
            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon_text);
            tv.setText(myRemoteViews[position]);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);
            iv.setImageResource(myRemoteImages[position]);

        } else {
            v = convertView;
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

XML File imageitem.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon_image" android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp">
    </ImageView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/icon_text" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="TextView"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:textColorHighlight="#656565">
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```